# Debug:: Writing a bootloader to an external drive directly from debug

Tags: debugging, assembly, dos, bootloader

Title says it all.... so let's go directly into ASSEMBLY :)

```
-A 100
1454:0100 mov ah,9
1454:0102 mov dx,109
1454:0105 int 21
1454:0107 int 20
1454:0109 db "Booting...$"
1454:0114

-rcx
CX0016
14
```

My goal is to use that simple code as a bootloader of an external hard drive.

I tried to write it to the current drive

```
-w 0 0 0 1
```

but obviosly it's protecting sector 0 so I want to write it to another drive without saving it to a bin file and use external softwares.

Small tweak needed here :D

Comment: Before even attempting to use this as a bootloader should point out `int 21` is a DOS interrupt and isn't available at boot time. You'll need to write directly to the video display or use BIOS interrupts.

Comment: You'll need external Windows software to permit the write because the NTVDM that allows 16-bit DOS programs like debug to run will not allow you to overwrite sector 0 of the disk.

Comment: You may also find using an assembler is useful to create bootloaders rather than using the old DOS debugger.

Comment: Besides changing your code to use BIOS software interrupts (instead of `int 21`) you'll also need to chain to the next boot loader (unless you goal is to simply write a message without booting into an OS). However, your bootloader will be in sector 0, so you'll need to have the next bootloader be elsewhere on BIOS drive 0, or else on another drive. In both cases you'd need to implement code to read the other bootloader's boot sector, setup registers, and jmp to it.